# .sh files from command prompt?

Tags: windows, userscripts

Can you call a `.sh` file from the windows command prompt using any of these programs.

For example:

```
msys myscript.sh
```

Or

```
c:\temp\msys.exe myscript.sh
```

Is it possible? As I would like to batch file running .sh scripts on one of my systems.

Answer (score 1):

`msys.exe` is one of a number of ports of Unix command-line tools. I haven't used it, but `msys.exe` appears to be the install package, so you need to run and configure it. If you want to have the tools readily available, and the installer does not do so, you will need to add the installed directory to your `PATH` variable.

To interpret a shell script you need `bash`, so in you example you would type:

```
bash -c myscript.exe
```

If all your scripts end in `.sh` (in Unix there is no need for a particular extension, and often there is none), you can associate the `.sh` extension with `bash`, so that you can then just type or double-click the script name.

Alternatively, you can run `bash` interatively instead of `cmd` and then all your commands will run as if on Unix.

Two points to watch:-

- If the scripts are imported from Unix, they will be *interpreted* correctly, but will not run if they call on commands or resources that either do not exist in Windows or have different functions.
- Unix uses `/` as a directory separator and `-` to signal command options, whereas Windows uses `\` and `/`. Some Unix command ports try to accommodate both styles, but because `/` has two different meanings, it is necessarily a poor compromise. I have no idea if `msys` attempts this.

Comment: I glossed over the association of `.sh` with `bash`. You cannot do it directly, because of the `-c` parameter, but it is still fairly easy to do.

Comment: Cool, we found that when msys is installed, you can rename the .sh scripts as the bat files and simply execute them in the standard command prompt. They functioned fully. Thanks

Comment: Fine. You will get all the programs that were installed, so they will be accessible from `cmd`, but the Linux shell syntax is very different from `cmd`'s, so any conditionals, loops, etc will need re-coding. Also, if you call another script the Linux shell returns and continues with the original script, whereas `cmd` chains to it and doesn't return, unless you precede the invocation with`CALL`. If the script is simply a sequence of programs with simple pipes and redirections, it will run OK in `cmd`.